# Update PWA application (react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I've got a PWA application that was created with `create-react-app`.

How to update my PWA application to get the latest change on the server, not from its caches?

I'm using react version +17 and using `serviceWorker` to create a PWA application with this CRA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update installed PWA apps by uninstalling and re-install them to get the latest changes.

But if you are familiar with the `ServiceWorker` on your CRA application, you can easily extend your service worker to update your application on every loading or any manual criteria.

open your service worker registration file and find `registerValidSW` function on it. add this line:

```
function registerValidSW(swUrl, config) {
  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register(swUrl)
    .then((registration) => {

      registration.update();        // <--------------- add this line ----

      registration.onupdatefound = () => {
        const installingWorker = registration.installing;
        if (installingWorker == null) {
          return;
        }
      }
    })
}
```

you can add an interval to update your application on period.

```
      // to update application on startup load
      registration.update();

      // create interval to update every 5 minutes
      setInterval(() => {
        registration.update();
        console.debug('Checked for update...');
      }, 1000 * 60 * 5);   // <--- this will update your application after 5 minutes.
```

Comment: using this type of variable (1000 * 60 * 5) is not my recommendation.
I'll rather create a constant outside of the code block and pass it to interval time.